# TeamCity Mercurial VCS root configuration fails

Tags: version-control, mercurial, teamcity

Teamcity is no more able to pull changes from a network share. Is this a user permission issue ? It was working until I upgraded from TeamCity 8.1.5 to TeamCity 9.0.2.

[image: Connection Test Fail]

Comment: Is the TeamCity service running under one of your network users or the built in Network Service account? That could cause this problem if the user it's running under doesn't have access to the network path.

Comment: The service is running under Local System Account. Where to change the user used to logon for this service and where to change and set the permission ?

Comment: https://confluence.jetbrains.com/display/TCD8/Installing+and+Configuring+the+TeamCity+Server#InstallingandConfiguringtheTeamCityServer-InstallingTeamCityviaWindowsinstallationpackage `Control Panel> Administrative Tools> Services`, but beware, this could cause the whole TeamCity service to fall over because it may create other permission issues that you'll have to manually fix where the new user doesn't have access to TeamCity folders or permissions to run a service, and particularly beware of running it under a user where their password is going to be forced to change regularly! Backup first!

Comment: Yes. The problem was, TeamCity Build Server and TeamCity Build Agent services were running under LocalSystem account. This is the default settings and in our domain, this LocalSystem account din't have the permission to access network shares. Solution was to change the service LogOn credential to use authenticated domain account. This can be done on service properties as you suggested.

Comment: That's great that that's working now. I notice that you have a very similar question just differently presented that you posted yesterday. It would be a good idea to integrate that information into this question and then delete the other one, that way any future attention for that sort of problem get directed to this solved question instead of the unanswered one.

Comment: Yeah. I deleted the duplicate

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem was, TeamCity Build Server and TeamCity Build Agent services were running under LocalSystem account. This is the default settings and in our domain, this LocalSystem account din't have the permission to access network shares. Solution was to change the service LogOn credential to use authenticated domain accounts which have access to the network share where we have the repository. This can be done on service properties as suggested by  @Nanhydrin.